# ServerScriptService.leaderstats:41: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats' in roblox

Tags: helper, roblox

This is my code

```
game:BindToClose(function(player)
    for _, Player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        
        local playerUserId = "player_"..Player.UserId

        local clicksValue = player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value

        local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
            clicksDataStore:SetAsync(playerUserId, clicksValue)
         
        end)
    end
end)
```

Please help me becouse I disconnect the game, console get me this error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `player.leaderstats` or `clicksValue` is not `nil` before calling:

```
local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
    clicksDataStore:SetAsync(playerUserId, clicksValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataModel:BindToClose` doesn't pass any arguments to the callback. I suggest you remove the `player` parameter in the callback and change the `player` in `player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value` to `Player`